# How come my setCenter doesn't work?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get my map to re-orient to a new center when a user
chooses a district within the main map from a dropdown menu. See the
map here: http://bilware.net/BullyMap/BullyMap.html

I can get the zoom to change using map.setZoom (although it's
commented out below). But map.setCenter won't work. I thought it was
because I wasn't calling LatLng parameters correctly, but discovered
it won't work even if I plug in fixed parameters, as I think I've done
below.

I'm very new to this; any help is appreciated.

```
function changeMap() {
var selected_bully_table = $('#map_menu').val();
var searchString = document.getElementById('searchString').value.replace("'", "\\'");
if(searchString == "") {
  layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry' FROM " + selected_bully_table);
  return;
  }
layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry' FROM " + selected_bully_table + " WHERE 'SDNAME' = '" + searchString + "'");

// Now zoom and center the map
{
map.setZoom(9);
myLatLng=(-91.9240850749,47.9119132072);
map.setCenter(myLatLng);
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
myLatLng=(-91.9240850749,47.9119132072);
```

with

```
myLatLng= new google.maps.LatLng(-91.9240850749,47.9119132072);
```

Comment: When I do that it returns a gray screen.

Answer (score 0):

your latitude value should be between -90 degrees and +90 degrees and also you should pass a new instance of google.maps.LatLng class to the setCenter function.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the two other answers will give you your real answer.

The reason doing

```
myLatLng= new google.maps.LatLng(-91.9240850749,47.9119132072);
```

gives you a gray screen is because the position is outside of the bounds of the map. If you zoom out and scroll the map upwards you will see this :)

What you need to do is write

```
map.setZoom(9);
myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(LATITUDE,LONGITUDE);
map.setCenter(myLatLng);
```

and pass values of LATITUDE & LONGITUDE that are within the bounds of the map like (51, 0).